# How to disable submit button whenever the form fields are empty?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a login form with some input fields such as "email" and "password". This form is created with real-time validation by Laravel and Livewire. Until now, everything is good.

With the livewire rules I want to disable the submit button if the form fields are null or empty with Alpine.js. How do I do that?

`app\Http\Livewire\LoginForm`

```php
class LoginForm extends Component
{
    public $email = '';
    public $password = '';

    protected $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:12',
    ];

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function saveUser()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();

        User::create($validatedData);
    }
}
```

`LoginForm Component`

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="saveUser">
    <input type="email" wire:model="email" class="form-control">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <input type="password" wire:model="password" class="form-control">
    @error('password') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <button type="submit">Login Now</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to use only Alpine JS or can I provide a version with Livewire too?

Comment: if you can provide me both please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply checking for the value iteself using blade

```
<button type="submit" {{ (!is_null($email) && !empty($email) && !is_null($password) && !empty($password)) ? '' : 'disabled' }}>Login Now</button>
```

Comment: correct thanks but if there is any trick to do the same thing but in shorten

Comment: @jhon-jhones checkout this answer on laracasts [disable submit button whenever the form fields are empty](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/alpinejs-disable-submit-button-whenever-the-form-fields-are-empty?page=1#reply=687588)

Answer (score 1):

<button type="submit" @if($errors->any()) disabled @endif>Save

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In you component you can use a separate property `public bool $canBeSubmitted` which hold the enabled/disabled state for the button.

```php
class LoginForm extends Component
{
    public $email = '';
    public $password = '';

    /**
     * Toggle disabled state of submit button
     */
    public bool $canBeSubmitted = false;

    protected $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:12',
    ];

    public function updated($email)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);

        // Setting $canBeSubmitted to true/false 
    }

    public function saveUser()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();

        User::create($validatedData);
    }
}
```

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="saveUser">
    <!-- inputs -->

    <button type="submit" {{ !empty($canBeSubmitted)) ? '' : 'disabled' }}>Login Now</button>
</form>
```

### AlpineJS and Livewire

To have access to the `canBeSubmitted` property from both, AlpineJS and Livewire, you can make use of the [`entangled` feature](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js).

From the docs:

> Livewire has an incredibly powerful feature called "entangle" that allows you to "entangle" a Livewire and Alpine property together. With entanglement, when one value changes, the other will also be changed.

Comment: the button still disabled even the from not empty ??